# Python IDLE icon appears for a second and then disappears, the IDLE doesn't start at all. - on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

I was working on Python IDLE editor on a Mac but for some reason now every time I click on the IDLE icon, it pops up in the doc for a second and then it just disappears. The IDLE just doesn't run anymore.

In one of the recommendations I found online, it says to type `/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -m idlelib`,  which I did in the console and it started up the Python shell, from which I can open a new file and start coding.

However, I would like to avoid doing this and be able to just start IDLE using the icon in the application folder.

I've downloaded and installed Homebrew, Pandas, PyCharm and among many others because I've seen some recommendations on installing these without complete understanding of them. I'm wondering if any of these programs altered something in the IDLE which is causing it to crash?

This is for Python 3.6 on Mac OS.

Comment: I was going to suggest starting IDLE from the console and see what error message was printed.  But you did and and ran fine.  That suggests that the icon is doing something else.  On Windows, I would right-click the icon, select 'Properties', and look at and possibly edit the startup directory and command fields.  Can you do something similar on MAC?  If the icon worked previously, then I suspect that it uses an environmental variable that was altered by one of the other installations.

Comment: No need to apologize for being a noob multiple times. Just say what you need and respond to comments that request more information. I edited out the cruft. Your question is pretty useful without it, so good job!

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I'm not too familiar with Mac as this is a new system for me having worked with Windows previously. I looked for the icon and then looked at the properties but not sure on what to look for. I've also tried doing 'idle3' in terminal console and it launches the shell properly which then I can start the edit file. However, in regards to launching it directly from the icon in application folder, I'm still stumped on that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for your advice and editing the content to make my posting efficient and to the point.

Comment: I've decided to move onto PyCharm to do the editing and running the codes. Thank you for your help